# How to declare NNEL (Non Null Except Locals) as default for an API with the Checker Framework

Tags: java, checker-framework

Past time manuals and Stackoverflow answers say that NNEL is the default in the Checker Framework. However, the recent manual (3.7.1) has no reference to that term any more.

I tried this on a package:

```
  @DefaultQualifier(value = NonNull.class,
    locations = {TypeUseLocation.RETURN, TypeUseLocation.PARAMETER, TypeUseLocation.FIELD, TypeUseLocation.UPPER_BOUND})
```

That works, however, I cannot declare:

```
public interface EntryProcessor<K, V, @Nullable R> { }
```

Which results in:

```
java: [bound.type.incompatible] incompatible bounds in type parameter
  type: R extends @Initialized @NonNull Object
  upper bound: @Initialized @NonNull Object
  lower bound: @Initialized @Nullable null
```

Questions:

- What is the default now?
- Would the concept NNEL include type parameters?
- How can I establish NNEL for a package or, even more logic, for a Java module (`module-info.java`) in the shortest form possible?
- If NEEL does not include type parameters, how can I establish the defaults so
  `EntryProcessor<K, V, @Nullable R>` means effectively `EntryProcessor<@NonNull K, @NonNull V, @Nullable R>`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a manual section ["Default qualifier for unannotated types"](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#defaults) about defaulting.
That section says:

> For example, the default qualifier for the Nullness Checker is `@NonNull`. When a user writes an unqualified type such as `Date`, the Nullness Checker interprets it as `@NonNull Date`.
>
> The type system applies that default qualifier to most but not all type uses. In particular, unless otherwise stated, every type system uses the CLIMB-to-top rule. This rule states that the top qualifier in the hierarchy is the default for the CLIMB locations: **C**asts, **L**ocals, and (some) **Im**plicit **B**ounds.

This is similar to the old "non-null except locals" description, but is more precisely stated and answers your question about type parameters.

> how can I establish the defaults so `EntryProcessor<K, V, @Nullable R>` means effectively `EntryProcessor<@NonNull K, @NonNull V, @Nullable R>`?

The bound `extends Object` is implicit, so it defaults to top per the CLIMB-to-top rule noted above.  (Top is `@Nullable` in the case of the Nullness Checker.)  This choice is necessary for [consistent treatment of types in source code](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#climb-to-top).

In your source code, you can write `@NonNull K`, `K extends Object`, or `K extends @NonNull Object`.

If you want to change the defaults, the code you gave is on the right track:

> `@DefaultQualifier(value = NonNull.class,`
>    `locations = {TypeUseLocation.RETURN, TypeUseLocation.PARAMETER, TypeUseLocation.FIELD, TypeUseLocation.UPPER_BOUND})`

In addition to `UPPER_BOUND`, there is an [`IMPLICIT_UPPER_BOUND`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/framework/qual/TypeUseLocation.html#IMPLICIT_UPPER_BOUND) value in the `TypeUseLocation` enum.  Is there a reason you chose not to include it?

Comment: Thanks a ton for the fast answer! I did not use IMPLICIT_UPPER_BOUND, since the NonNull assumption should be default for the EXPLICIT_UPPER_BOUND as well. Do I need to specify both? What does UPPER_BOUND mean then?

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning. `The latter would forbid instantiations such as C<@Nullable String>, or would require rewriting of code`. Assuming, which is default now, `Date` means `@NonNull Date` requires rewriting code, too. As I understand it, the whole checking is about rewriting code, since we want to improve it :)

Comment: I tried with IMPLICIT_UPPER_BOUND, does not work either with exactly the same error message.

Comment: You did not answer the part of "in the shortest form". I will put up another question that illustrates that better.